# How can I pass a values from my controller to my view?

Tags: grails

I am using grails 3. I have some values in my Controller, say

```
[view: "user", model: [user: user]]
```

and in user.gsp I am writing

```
${user.name}
```

but this doesn't work in grails 3. I also tried it like this

```
render (view: "/views/user.gsp", model: [user: user])
```

in my controller but still its showing the following error:

```
Could not resolve view with name 'save' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'
```

Comment: Give us a bit more code. It seems like you are trying to render a file with name "save.gsp" (which is not there). Post full method.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please improve your question with a code sample.

Answer (score 0):

The code in the second part of your question looks for the following .gsp file:

.../grails-app/views/views/user.gsp

I assume you want something like this

```
render (view: "/user.gsp", model: [user: user])
```

This will look in the following directory:

.../grails-app/views/user.gsp,

Useful Sources:

- http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#gsp
- http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#modelsAndViews

Answer (score 0):

It seems your view file is located at `grails-app/views/user.gsp`. You did not give us the of name your controller, so I will make one up and pretend it is called "YourController" (I will also presume you are not using controller namespaces).

To have the controller find the view automatically (as in your first attempt) you would need to name it `grails-app/views/your/user.gsp` since controllers look for 'their' folders by default.

Your second attempt to provide the full path is wrong in two aspects: first, you do not need to explicitly add the `/views` part of the path (unless you have a `grails-app/views/views` folder), your views cannot reside outside of `grails-app/views`. Second, you must not append the `.gsp` extension, Grails will figure it out on its own (because you have other options than just `.gsp` files and Grails will pick the most appropriate one for the request). So the second form should read: `render (view: "/user", model: [user: user])`